# Provider com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem could not be instantiated

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, google-cloud-storage, hadoop2, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to install the Google Cloud Storage on Spark. I have added "gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar" in the hadoop classpath using `-libjars`. I'm still getting the `GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem` class not found error.

```
$ hadoop fs -libjars /PATH/gcs-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar -ls /HDFS_PATH
20/02/05 05:41:33 WARN fs.FileSystem: Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem could not be instantiated
20/02/05 05:41:33 WARN fs.FileSystem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/hadoop/gcsio/GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem
20/02/05 05:41:33 WARN fs.FileSystem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem
20/02/05 05:41:33 WARN fs.FileSystem: Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem could not be instantiated
20/02/05 05:41:33 WARN fs.FileSystem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/hadoop/gcsio/GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem
20/02/05 05:41:33 WARN fs.FileSystem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem
```

Is there anything i'm missing here?

Comment: Could you post the code you are using? Furthermore, can you check that you added the connector to the Hadoop/Spark classpath? Lastly, I would encourage you to check if you followed the steps in the documentation: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md

Comment: @Alexandre Moraes just the `hadoop fs -ls` command is throwing that warning.

Comment: this error GoogleHadoopFileSystem most likely related to the connector not being part of the classpath. I would recommend you to inspect your .jar file you are using and check if the file GoogleHadoopFileSystem.class is missing. Can you do that ?

Comment: I've verified that. GoogleHadoopFileSystem class is present in the *.jar file I've mentioned in the `libjars`.

Comment: Next step I would suggest is to download a fresh .jar file and try if it works.

Comment: can you give me an update?

Comment: i've downloaded a fresh jar. But still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to the master node of your dataproc cluster you can add the gcs connector and symlink here `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib`